# Ultrasonic range sensors in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, sonar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've been trying to find a robot with at least one ultrasonic range sensor that is already simulated in Gazebo so I can see how it is programmed, but I can't find any, and I see that there isn't a question about this (or I can't find it, of course...)

Thanks in advance!
Miguel.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32490/ultrasonic-range-sensors-in-gazebo/) by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [reem_common](https://github.com/pal-robotics/reem_common/tree/electric) and [reem_plugins](https://github.com/pal-robotics/reem_plugins/tree/electric) stacks (they work with ROS Electric). They respectively contain examples of a URDF model with sonars/IRs, and plugins for simulating such sensors in gazebo. HTH.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-04-25**:
Thanks Adolfo, I'll look into it but it seems to be exactly what I wanted :)

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2012-08-30**:
could you compile the package reem_plugins with rosmake in fuerte? It gives me problems with the includes path like gazebo/Sonar.hh, gazebo / Global.hh etc.

I find Sensor.hh but I but not Global.hh Where must I looking for this header?

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2012-09-04**:
The package has no fuerte support. In fact, it will probably never have, but rather jump to Groovy. Feel free to send a patch to our github issue tracker if you ever migrate it to Fuerte.